# Hive find expected run time of query

Tags: runtime, hive, hiveql

I want to find the expected run time of query in Hive. Using EXPLAIN gives the execution plan. Is there a way to find the expected time?

I need Hive equivalent of SQL query EXPLAIN COSTS .

Comment: I really liked the idea. Please do let us know if you find some direct way to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no OOTB feature at this moment that facilitates this. One way to achieve this would be to learn from history. Gather patterns based on similar data and queries you have run previously and try to deduce some insights. You might find tools like [Starfish](https://www.cs.duke.edu/starfish/release.html) helpful in the process.

I would not recommend you to decide anything based on a subset of your data, as running queries on a small dataset and on the actual dataset are very different. This is good to test the functionality but not for any kind of cost approximation. The reason behind this is that a lot of factors are involved in the process, like system resources(disk, CPU slots, N/W etc), system configuration, other running jobs etc. You might find smooth operation on a small dataset, but as the data size increases all these factors start playing much important role. Even a small configuration parameter may play an important role.(You might have noticed sometimes that a Hive query runs fast initially but starts getting slow gradually). Also, execution of a Hive query is much more involved than a simple MR job.

See this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1938), to get some idea, where they are talking about developing a Cost Based Query optimization for Joins in Hive. You might also find [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-33) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible to because internally map reduce gets executed for any particular Hive query. Moreover map reduce job's execution time depends on the cluster load and its configuration. So it is tough to predict the execution time. May be you can do one thing you can use some timer before running the query and then after that finishes up you can calculate the exact execution time that was needed for execution.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could sample a small % of records from your table using partitions , bucket features etc then run the query against the small dataset. Note the execution time and then multiply with the factor (total_size/sample_size).